# DeprecatingWarning: with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting deprecatingWarning even though I have:

`mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;`

```
var express = require('express');
var responseTime = require('response-time');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/user');
var Task = require('../models/task');
var Rating = require('../models/rating');
var Skill = require('../models/skill');
var Match = require('../models/match');
var UserSkill = require('../models/user_skill');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PORT_NUMBER = 3000;

// response-time middleware (adds X-Response-Header to responses)
app.use(responseTime());
//
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://useyourown');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/create', function(req,res){
    let newTask = new Task();

    newTask.name = req.body.name;
    newTask.experience = req.body.experience;
    newTask.user_id = req.body.user_id;
    newTask.rating = req.body.rating;

    newTask.save(function(err, task){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Task saved: " + task.name);
        }
        res.redirect('hearbeat');
    });
});
```

Now when I am testing this with Postman my console is giving me this error:

```
DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

and because of this it is not working properly. 
There is a lot of people with this kind of error, however adding Promise fixed it for them. I don't understand why it is now working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass promise library to mongoose.Promise everywere where You requiring mongoose, eg. in app.js, in shcema/model files, in test files

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Instead using native global.Promise I recoomended use Bluebird promise library, Its much faster: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that I had to put it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have found :

> "Yes, it appears that setting the mongoose. Promise in the schema
>   files where mongoose.model is exported eliminates the warning in
>   mongoose versions 4.8 and later."

I think you should check your version again.